# Invoke-WebRequest in an own function with arguments

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to run an Invoke-WebRequest command on PowerShell Core 6.3 on a Ubuntu system with the following settings to create a forwarder:

```
$userLocalMailPart = "user"
$userGlobalMailPart = "Hotmail.com"
$address = "Some Address"
$pair = $login + ":" + $password
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"

$url = "https://" + $server + ":" + $port + "/Domain/ObjectList.html"

$headers = @{"Authorization" = $basicAuthValue;
    "Referer"                = $url
}
$body = @{
    "NewForwarderName"    = $userLocalMailPart ;
    "NewForwarderAddress" = $address;
    "CreateForwarder"     = "Create Forwarder"
}
$result = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Uri $url `
    -SkipCertificateCheck `
    -Method 'POST' `
    -Headers $headers `
    -Body $body
```

This runs perfectly. No error and the forwarder is successfully created.
Now I want to use a function like this:

```
[Web]::requestHeaderContent($url, $headers, (ConvertTo-Json($body)), 'POST')


[object] static requestHeaderContent([String] $url, [hashtable] $headers, [Object] $body, [String] $meth) {
    Invoke-WebRequest `
        -Uri $url `
        -SkipCertificateCheck `
        -Method $meth `
        -Headers $headers `
        -Body $body
}
```

The variables like headers and body are the same. I also tried it with ConvertTo-Json but it just don’t work. I also receive a Success 200 Code but the forwarder is not created. I guess my problem are the parameters. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Stephan

Comment: You are right. The ) is a copy-paste error. And you are also right, in the first example I dont do the conversation, but as I said, I also tried it with and without it.